# Как сохранить состояние CardView в RecyclerView при переходе из Activity?

Tags: android, recyclerview

В Activity есть RecyclerView, в котором содержатся CardView. В CardView есть две кнопки и текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В адаптере задается нужное число для TextView, например, 5. Но при выходе из Activity и повторном возврате в него число из TextView теряется, так как карточка добавляется повторно запросом GET при пересоздании Activity. Как сделать, чтобы значение числа в TextView сохранялось(при возврате в Activity оставалось 5).

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно сохранять состояние items в памяти, например в SharedPreferences

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. Например в данном случае можно показать как записать/считать что-то из SharedPreferences

Comment: Почему не в корзине на сервере?